# Formatting to save to .PDF and take up entire page

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am creating an excel document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel via C#.  I am able to successfully create and save to a .pdf file.

The issue I am having is that when saved to a .pdf file it doesn't take up the entire page.  This causes my data to appear smaller and squished.  Is there a way to specify all white space is used while fitting all the data on one page?

```
newWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(ExcelApp.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
                                               fullFileName,
                                                   ExcelApp.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityMinimum,
                                                       true,
                                                           true,
                                                               misValue,
                                                                   misValue,
                                                                       false,
                                                                           misValue);
```

Comment: I use `xlQualityStandard` which seems to work good for me.  Not sure if that'll fix your issue though.

Comment: Generally, what works in the UI works with the object model, so it would be best to explore (in an end-user venue) what options, if any, are available to allow this. My gut feeling, however, is that the data will need to be formatted in Excel, i.e. font size.